# Upsell : get parent product from child product id

Tags: magento-1.7

i am looking for code which can help me get parent product id from child product Id and this both products are related using upsell feature

so far i was able to retrieve child products id from parent id by using below code

```
   //Get product detail using product id  (Suppose you have product id is : $product_id)
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

   // Fetch list of upsell product using query.
   $upsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```

but i want to do reverse

This solution also worked

```
$childProductId = 17;//edit this value, or get it by $product->getId()
$productsLinkedAsUpsell = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('linked_product_id', $childProductId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('link_type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL);
foreach ($productsLinkedAsUpsell as $upsell) {
    $parentId = $upsell->getProductId();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will:

1. Get the link instance of the current product,
2. Filter based on the linked_product_id column on the table `catalog_product_link`,
3. The call to useUpSellLinks will make sure only upselling links are returned,
4. Give you a collection of all links where this product is set in the linked_product_id,

You can then loop through the collection and get the product_id attribute which will be the parent.

```
//Get product detail using product id  (Suppose you have product id is : $product_id)
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

// Fetch list of upsell product using query.
$_linkInstance = $_product->getLinkInstance();
/* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Collection */
$collection = $_linkInstance->useUpSellLinks()->getLinkCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('linked_product_id',  array('eq' => $_product->getId()));
$collection->addLinkTypeIdFilter();
$collection->joinAttributes();

foreach($collection as $upsellproduct) {
    $upsellproduct->getProductId();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty way of doing it:

```
$productId = 1;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
//$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');//if you want all the attributes
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$joinCondition = array(
    'links.linked_product_id = e.entity_id',
    'links.link_type_id = '. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL
);
$select->join(
    array('links' => $collection->getTable('catalog/product_link')),
    implode(' AND ', $joinCondition),
    array('link_id')
);
$select->where('links.linked_product_id = ?', (int)$productId);
foreach ($collection as $item){
    //do something with $item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get parent (configurable) product of a child product on product listing or product view page template in magento, you can achieve this by using 1 line code as below :

```
if (empty(Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId()))
echo $product->getName();
```

Reference : http://magentomonsters.com/get-parent-product-of-child-product-in-magento/

Comment: Be careful when using empty(), you'd need php 5.5 or higher to use it with some different than a variable http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

For related, upsell, crossell products also possible to use

```
$parentIds = $product->getLinkInstance()->getResource()
    ->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED);
```